# Unregister callbacks from dojo.Deferred

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there any way to unregister callbacks from dojo.Deferred? If not why?

Comment: I would urge the dojo fellows to pls add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/Deferred.html), there isn't. Shouldn't be too hard to add one though:

```
dojo.Deferred.prototype.removeCallback = function(fn) {
    for (var c = this.chain, i = c.length; i--;)
        if (c[i][0] === fn) c.splice(i, 1);
    return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
var d = new dojo.Deferred;
d.addCallback(someFn);
// Remove it:
d.removeCallback(someFn);
```